# Blazor Server with Entity Framework core, How call DB methods Asyncronously

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

I creating balzor server app with ASP.net core 3.1 and Entity framework core.
The problem is that since Db call takes a while to get back record and there is no built in async into EF core, i decided to delay pulling rows after few seconds once page loads.
But the problem is that my HTML does not update after code has run.
Without Task Delay i can see data. Why is it not updating my UI/HTML ?

Html

```
@if (_allRequestForHelp.Count > 0)
{
   @foreach (var item in _allRequestForHelp)
    {

   }
}



protected override void OnInitialized()
    {

        telemetryClient.TrackPageView("RegisterForHelp");

       // want to run this async other page hangs until the data comesback
        Task.Delay(2000).ContinueWith(t => loadPreviousRequestForHelps());

        base.OnInitialized();
    }



private async Task loadPreviousRequestForHelps()
    {

            if (appStateInfo.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                _allRequestForHelp =  (from b in dbContext.RequestHelp where b.UserID.ToString() == appStateInfo.UserID orderby b.UTCDateCreated descending select b).ToList();
                StateHasChanged();

            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the async version OnInitialized

protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()

everything else remains same and it is working now